# Execute multiple JCL job with same name simultaneously

Tags: sorting, jcl

I have a requirement to run same job multiple times using different datasets. These jobs take some time to execute so I want to submit multiple jobs together. How Can I run these jobs simultaneously ?
Job name should be like XXXXXXX1, XXXXXXX2,XXXXXXX3, XXXXXXX4 and so on. How can I dynamically assign jobname through JCL ?